# Variable with multiple values

Tags: python

I'm completely new to python(2.7.13) and had a question about assigning values to variables. What is the difference between var1 and var2?

```
sentence = "Today is sunny."

var1 = sentence.split(' ')
var2 = "Today", "is", "sunny."

print var1
print var2
```

When I run the program it shows as the following:

['Today', 'is', 'sunny.']

('Today', 'is', 'sunny.')

What is the significance of the parentheses and square brackets there?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference here is that `var1` is a list and `var2` is a tuple.

A list is denoted by the square brackets, `[]`, and it is a mutable element that stores multiple values. Mutable means that after you create it, you can change the value or the values inside without assigning a totally new value to the variable.

A tuple is denoted by the parentheses, `()`. It is similar to a list, but immutable. Thus, you will get an error if you try to change a value within the tuple after you instantiate (create and assign a value to) it.

Check out these links for more information:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm

Answer (score 0):

Its creating a list in variable one notice the [] rather than ().